# Codepipeline no matcing artifacts found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-codepipeline

I m trying to deploy sam app with codepipieline, I am receiving following error log

```
Running command sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $BUCKET --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml  
Uploading to d9f08f2a91c5f1bede6a22e7f8ecbcfc  46320 / 46320.0  (100.00%)
Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file outputSamTemplate.yaml.

[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
Build completed on Mon Apr 6 09:08:46 UTC 2020

[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Expanding base directory path: .
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Expanding .
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Expanding file paths for base directory .
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Assembling file list
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Expanding template.yml
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Skipping invalid file path template.yml
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Expanding outputSamTemplate.yml
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Skipping invalid file path outputSamTemplate.yml
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/04/06 09:08:46 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found
```

I have researched online and it says that my path files might be invalid but I am pretty sure they are correct, thus this error message is confuing...

my buildspec:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
  pre_build:
    commands:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - export BUCKET=inspeq-sam
      - sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $BUCKET --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml
  post_build:
    commands:
      - ls
      - pwd
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template.yml
    - outputSamTemplate.yml
```

[image: repo structure]

I have added commands to list content of folder in after build. Those files are listed there.

```
[Container] 2020/04/06 10:38:55 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/04/06 10:38:55 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/04/06 10:38:55 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2020/04/06 10:38:55 Running command pwd
/codebuild/output/src927271356/src

[Container] 2020/04/06 10:38:55 Running command ls
README.md
buildspec.yml
hello-world
outputSamTemplate.yaml
template.yaml
test.iml

[Container] 2020/04/06 10:38:55 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
Build completed on Mon Apr 6 10:38:55 UTC 2020

[Container] 2020/04/06 10:38:55 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
```

Comment: Have you created role? Check IAM permissions.

Comment: aws iam list-roles?

Comment: Hey, but roles for what ? CF , codebuild ?

Comment: Cloudformation,Sam builds on top.

Comment: service role that is connected with codebuild has admin access rights,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'yml', you need 'yaml':

```
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template.yaml
    - outputSamTemplate.yaml
```